# chaquopy package build Error: make[1]: *** [../Makefile.tail:40: libs] Error 127

Tags: cmake, makefile, chaquopy

I wanted to use a newer version of numpy with chaquopy, that is not prebuild in the official repository, so i tried to buil it myself using the chaquopy package build tool. Because numpy relies on chaquopy-openblas i tried to build that first, however i get this error message:

```
make[1]: /home/default/Coding/chaquopy/server/pypi/packages/chaquopy-openblas/build/0.2.20/py3-none-android_21_armeabi_v7a/wrappers/armv7a-linux-androideabi21-ar: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [../Makefile.tail:40: libs] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/default/Coding/chaquopy/server/pypi/packages/chaquopy-openblas/build/0.2.20/py3-none-android_21_armeabi_v7a/src/interface'
make: *** [Makefile:139: libs] Error 1
build-wheel: Error: Command '['/home/default/Coding/chaquopy/server/pypi/packages/chaquopy-openblas/build.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

Comment: The *useful* error message is in the **first line**: `/home/default/Coding/chaquopy/server/pypi/packages/chaquopy-openblas/build/0.2.20/py3-none-android_21_armeabi_v7a/wrappers/armv7a-linux-androideabi21-ar: No such file or directory`. Following error messages are just result of propagation of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build chaquopy-openblas, or any other `host` requirement from the meta.yaml file. Just download a pre-built copy from [the public repository](https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/) into your `dist` directory.

For more details, see the scikit-learn example in [the README](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/blob/master/server/pypi/README.md).